# How to make a screen appear after an event with PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I've started to create a kind of LMS where the goal is for an user to enter accounting entries in the order to be evaluated on these entrie (it' a boolean function, if the entry is correct, the user get 1 point, or the writing is wrong).
So I chose the PyQt5 library to make the welcome menu page, where the user can register himself (the data is kept in an SQLite table) and authenticate (the same data recorded during authentication is queried), until there no problem.

Then I created a class and an attribute relating to the "exercise screen" (using QtDesigner), i.e. the window the subject of the exercise.

Where I am blocking is to display this screen (the "exercise screen") after successful authentication. I would like, once the username and the password entered are correct, make it appear, without creating an additional window, the screen relating to the exercise.

I was having an error message at the beginning, saying that I have no attribute in the login class but now I've write some additional code, I haven't this particular error anymore.

I put you the code below and the screenshots of the screens that are called during the execution of the program:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget 
import sqlite3

class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("welcomescreen.ui", self)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.gotologin)
        self.create.clicked.connect(self.gotocreate)

    def gotologin(self):
        login = LoginScreen()
        widget.addWidget(login)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

    def gotocreate(self):
        create = CreateAccScreen()
        widget.addWidget(create)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)

class LoginScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("login.ui", self)
        self.passwordfield.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)

    def loginfunction(self):
        user = self.usernamefield.text()
        password = self.passwordfield.text()
        bookkeeping = BookKeepingScreen()

    def gotobookkeeping(self):
        BookKeepingScreen = BookKeepingScreen()
        widget.addWidget(BookKeepingScreen)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)

        if len(user)==0 or len(password)==0:
            self.error.setText("Veuillez remplir tous les champs")
        else : 
            conn = sqlite3.connect("logindata.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            query = 'SELECT password FROM login_info WHERE username =\''+user+"\'"
            cur.execute(query)
            result_pass = cur.fetchone()[0]
            if result_pass == password:
                print("Authentification réussie !")
                self.error.setText("")
                self.bookkeeping.connect(self.gotobookkeeping)
            
            else :
                self.error.setText("nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe invalide...")

class BookKeepingScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BookKeepingScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("bookkeeping.ui", self)

    def BookKeepingfunction(self):
        def loginfunction(self):
            compte = self.case_compte_1.text()
            libelle = self.case_libelle_1.text()
            debit = self.case_debit_1.text()
            credit = self.case_credit_1.text()

        if len(compte)==401:
            self.error.setText("Ce n'est pas le bon compte")

        else : 
            conn = sqlite3.connect("logindata.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            query = 'SELECT libelle FROM pcg WHERE compte = "401"'
            cur.execute(query)
            result_validation = cur.fetchone()[0]
            if result_validation == compte:
                print("+1")
                conn = sqlite3.connect("logindata.db")
                cur = conn.cursor()

                user_info = [user, info, level]
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO login_info (username, password, level) VALUES (+1)', user_info)

                conn.commit()
                conn.close() 

class CreateAccScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CreateAccScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("createacc.ui", self)
        self.passwordfield.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.confirmpasswordfield.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.senregistrerButton.clicked.connect(self.senregistrerButtonfunction)

    def senregistrerButtonfunction(self):
        user = self.usernamefield.text()
        password = self.passwordfield.text()
        confirmpassword = self.confirmpasswordfield.text()

        if len(user)==0 or len(password)==0 or len(confirmpassword)==0:
            self.error.setText("Veuillez remplir tous les champs")

        elif password!=confirmpassword:
            self.error.setText("Les mots de passes ne correspondent pas")
        else : 
            conn = sqlite3.connect("logindata.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()

            user_info = [user, password]
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO login_info (username, password) VALUES (?,?)', user_info)

            conn.commit()
            conn.close() 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = WelcomeScreen()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedHeight(800)
widget.setFixedHeight(1200)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question and code are somehow confusing, so it's a bit difficult to really help you, as there are *many* issues, some logical, others practical, and the code you provided is also insufficient to run it (it's missing the ui files). For instance, the `gotobookkeeping` function is never called, and even if it would, it would crash your program as it uses undefined variables and attributes (`user`, `password`, `self.bookkeeping`); also, the `loginfunction` does absolutely nothing, since it creates *local* variables that are immediately destroyed as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Be aware that it's clear that you're following a tutorial that is known for providing ***terrible*** suggestions and teaching ***a lot*** of bad practices. Just some examples: 1. you should *not* add QDialogs to a QStackedWidget (try pressing the Esc key and you'll see); 2. a stacked widget is intended to *cycle* through *existing* widgets (just like a tab widget, without the tabs), not continuously adding them; 3. the page switching with `currentIndex() + 1` is unreliable; 4. it doesn't use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) nor it's made aware of font scaling issues;

Comment: 5. it shouldn't be a child's responsibility to switch between pages, but its parent's; also, using the generic "global" `widget` reference in an instance method is not good and prone to NameErrors and consequent crashes; 6. the database queries are unchecked, badly constructed and unsafe; 7. the `try/except` block at the end is just *wrong*, as you don't have *NO* way to know what went wrong if the program crashes. These are only few examples (in the original there are even more issues); I'm sorry for you, I tried to contact the author, but it seems they really don't care, as I got no reply.